# Which is better or alternative way other than Function in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, function, lambda

I have a click stream data. I am using URL column to find out special event. For example if the URL contains keyword Dealer then the new column will be created "Is Dealer" which gives Boolean value.

**df sample:**

[image: **df example:**]

**Dictionary:**
I have a dictionary where key is "Domain" and values are the list of keywords (keyword must be checked in URL"

```
brand_dict = {'volkswagen': ['haendlersuche'], 'mercedes-benz': ['dealer-locator'], 'skoda-auto': ['dealers']}
```

I need to check 2 condition in other columns first: If Domains column = "BMW" and it contains any keyword from the list of dictionary then it gives boolean value in new column.

The problem is that i have to create 3 columns and I have 3 dictionaries. Any special way to do this?

So far i am doing this:

```
 def conv_attribution(domain, url):

        list_output = []

        if domain in dict_config.keys():


            bolcheck1 = False
            for keyword in dict_config[domain]:
                if keyword in url:
                    bolcheck1 = True

            bolcheck2 = False
            for keyword in dict_dealer[domain]:
                if keyword in url:
                    bolcheck2 = True  

            bolcheck3 = False
            for keyword in dict_brand_keywords[domain]:
                if keyword in url:
                      bolcheck3 = True


            if bolcheck1 == True:
                list_output.append(True)
            else:
                list_output.append(False)

            if bolcheck2 == True:
                list_output.append(True)
            else:
                list_output.append(False)

            if bolcheck3 == True:
                list_output.append(keyword)
            else:
                list_output.append("Nan")


   return list_output
```

Please help...

**Desired Output**

The desired out would look like this but in Model Name, I want to add model name extracted from URL

[image]

Comment: Can you provide a sample dataframe and then desired output? [See this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Comment: Thanks. I just added the desired output and sample

Comment: If I am not wrong you have 2 more dictionaries similar to brand_dict?

Comment: Also, what do you mean by `I want to add model name extracted from URL`? Do you want to replace the boolean flag with the key from dictionary or is it something else?

Comment: In output 2 columns "event_config" and "event_dealer"are working fine. But in last column its providing also boolean values, I want the keyword that extracted from the url in last column.

Comment: Yes i have 2 more dictionaries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is a minimal example

```
import pandas as pd
domains = ['bmw','smart','smart','fiat','bmw']
urls = ['https://bmw.com/hello','https://smart.com/world','https://smart.com/hello','https://fiat.com/hello','https://bmw.com/hello']
df = pd.DataFrame({'domain':domains,'urls':urls})
# your config dict
brand_dict = {'bmw': ['hello'], 'smart': ['world'],'fiat':['hello']}
```

sample df

```
    domain  urls
0   bmw     https://bmw.com/hello
1   smart   https://smart.com/world
2   smart   https://smart.com/hello
3   fiat    https://fiat.com/hello
4   bmw     https://bmw.com/hello
```

create new columns

```
df['col_1'] = df.apply(lambda x: any(substring in x.urls for substring in brand_dict[x.domain]) ,axis =1)
df['col_2'] = df.apply(lambda x: any(substring in x.urls for substring in brand_dict[x.domain]) ,axis =1)
df
```

new df

```
   domain   urls                    col_1   col_2
0   bmw     https://bmw.com/hello   True    True
1   smart   https://smart.com/world True    True
2   smart   https://smart.com/hello False   False
3   fiat    https://fiat.com/hello  True    True
4   bmw     https://bmw.com/hello   True    True
```

Comment: This is best solution until yet for me. I actually want to add another column in the end. I have dictionary for that too. For example: if domain = fiat  and url contains hello then the new column should have value hello.

Comment: add another apply statement for that

Comment: Yes but i dont want value as boolean in 3rd column. I want it as keyword which found in url.

Comment: you can also return a substring that matches in the function

Comment: suggest you read about lambda function and apply examples from pandas documentation